# WooCommerce Checkout Page delivery date-picker get client date rather than server date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce Checkout Page delivery date-picker get client date rather than server date.

A client from a different time zone that wants to purchase for same day delivery will not be able to do it.

I'm using Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce for the date-picker

I'm looking for a solution please

Comment: You will have to do this with javascript as PHP only runs and knows about the server. Then it would seem prudent to pass this to the server using AJAX